# How to enable TinyMCE text editor on TextareaType?

Tags: tinymce, prestashop, symfony-forms, prestashop-1.7

I am working on a PrestaShop module and I need to implement a TextArea that uses TinyMCE in a form using Symfony FormType with the function buildForm(), I have tried [the solution from the documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/form/types-reference/formatted-textarea/#formattedtextareatype).

But nothing happens, it just renders a simple textarea instead, maybe the doc doesn't mention some steps I have to do in order to activate it?

Answer (score 0):

Just give an id to your TextareaType like this

```
->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
  'label' => 'Description',
  'attr' => [
  'id' => 'tiny-mce-id'
  ]
])
```

Next you just need to add in your twig template

```
<script>
   $('textarea#tiny-mce-id').tinymce({    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to add the [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/jquery/) library to your project